# How can I override beans created by a @Configuration in a single test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**tldr** I am trying to override the application settings used by integration tests for *a single test* in order to use [Testcontainers](https://testcontainers.com/guides/replace-h2-with-real-database-for-testing/). I have unsuccessfully tried various approaches.

All existing integration tests use the H2 database through a `@Configuration` annotated class called `TestConfig`, seen below.

At first I tried setting `@TestPropertySource` annotations on the class and some setup using `@DynamicPropertySource`, [as shown in this guide](https://testcontainers.com/guides/replace-h2-with-real-database-for-testing/?_gl=1*1o7ywgx*_up*MQ..*_ga*MTUyNzEzNTc4OC4xNzAwMDI0NTQy*_ga_22TYV8FBPD*MTcwMDAyNDU0MC4xLjEuMTcwMDAyNDU1My4wLjAuMA..#_testing_jdbctemplate_based_repositories), modified to work with JUnit 4 (using `@ClassRule`). That did not seem to do anything. I also had a look at the [Quickstart for JUnit 4](https://java.testcontainers.org/quickstart/junit_4_quickstart/) to see if I was missing something, but alas ...

I then started hacking, *commenting out* the `dataSource()` method in `TestConfig`, so that no `DataSource` bean was available, and *then* I was able to make the test run using my TestContainers setup, so there is some kind of ordering or precedence I need to control.

As can be seen below, the `TestConfig` class filters out the normal database config and application config, and creates alternate beans for the context.

**TestConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.base.package", "com.base.commons"},
    excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = ApplicationConfig.class), 
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = DatabaseConfig.class),
    })
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean // this is what I want to override!
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2);
        return builder.build();
    }
```

**RateLimiterTest.java**

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
public class RateLimiterTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @ClassRule
    public static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:11")
            .withDatabaseName("prop")
            .withUsername("postgres")
            .withPassword("pass")
            .withExposedPorts(5432);

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void registerPgProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url",
                () -> String.format("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:%d/prop", postgres.getFirstMappedPort()));
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", () -> "postgres");
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", () -> "pass");
    }
```

How can I override the `TestConfig#dataSource()` method in a "proper" way?

I also tried extending `TestConfig` like this and using this subclass in the single test class:

```
class PostgresTestConfig extends TestConfig {
    @Override
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final var hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:tc:postgresql:15:///databasename");
        return hikariDataSource;
    }
}
```

While that worked perfectly for this single test instance, it seems to leak out and change the "global" Spring setup, as `mvn test` will now fail on all subsequent tests, as it seems no beans can be created/found:

```
============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   AbstractBulkheadConfigurationOnMissingBean#bulkheadRegistry matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.github.resilience4j.bulkhead.BulkheadRegistry; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   AbstractBulkheadConfigurationOnMissingBean#compositeBulkheadCustomizer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: compositeBulkheadCustomizer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   AbstractBulkheadConfigurationOnMissingBean#compositeThreadPoolBulkheadCustomizer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: compositeThreadPoolBulkheadCustomizer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   AbstractBulkheadConfigurationOnMissingBean#threadPoolBulkheadRegistry matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.github.resilience4j.bulkhead.ThreadPoolBulkheadRegistry; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   AbstractCircuitBreakerConfigurationOnMissingBean#compositeCircuitBreakerCustomizer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: compositeCircuitBreakerCustomizer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   AbstractRateLimiterConfigurationOnMissingBean#compositeRateLimiterCustomizer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: compositeRateLimiterCustomizer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   AbstractRateLimiterConfigurationOnMissingBean#rateLimiterRegistry matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.github.resilience4j.ratelimiter.RateLimiterRegistry; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   AbstractRetryConfigurationOnMissingBean#compositeRetryCustomizer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: compositeRetryCustomizer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   AbstractRetryConfigurationOnMissingBean#retryRegistry matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.github.resilience4j.retry.RetryRegistry; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   AbstractTimeLimiterConfigurationOnMissingBean#compositeTimeLimiterCustomizer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: compositeTimeLimiterCustomizer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   AbstractTimeLimiterConfigurationOnMissingBean#timeLimiterRegistry matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.github.resilience4j.timelimiter.TimeLimiterRegistry; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.auto=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration.ClassProxyingConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class 'org.aspectj.weaver.Advice' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   ApplicationAvailabilityAutoConfiguration#applicationAvailability matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.availability.ApplicationAvailability; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   BulkheadAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'io.github.resilience4j.bulkhead.Bulkhead' (OnClassCondition)

   BulkheadAutoConfiguration.BulkheadEndpointAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint' (OnClassCondition)

   BulkheadConfigurationOnMissingBean#bulkheadEventConsumerRegistry matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.github.resilience4j.bulkhead.event.BulkheadEvent; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   BulkheadMetricsAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry', 'io.github.resilience4j.bulkhead.Bulkhead', 'io.github.resilience4j.micrometer.tagged.TaggedBulkheadMetricsPublisher' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (resilience4j.bulkhead.metrics.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   BulkheadMetricsAutoConfiguration#taggedBulkheadMetricsPublisher matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (resilience4j.bulkhead.metrics.legacy.enabled=false) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'simpleMeterRegistry'; @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.github.resilience4j.micrometer.tagged.TaggedBulkheadMetricsPublisher; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   CacheMeterBinderProvidersConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.MeterBinder' (OnClassCondition)

   CircuitBreakerAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreaker' (OnClassCondition)

   CircuitBreakerAutoConfiguration.CircuitBreakerEndpointAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint' (OnClassCondition)

   CircuitBreakerConfigurationOnMissingBean#eventConsumerRegistry matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.event.CircuitBreakerEvent; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   CircuitBreakerMetricsAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry', 'io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreaker', 'io.github.resilience4j.micrometer.tagged.TaggedCircuitBreakerMetricsPublisher' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (resilience4j.circuitbreaker.metrics.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   CircuitBreakerMetricsAutoConfiguration#taggedCircuitBreakerMetricsPublisher matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (resilience4j.circuitbreaker.metrics.legacy.enabled=false) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'simpleMeterRegistry'; @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.github.resilience4j.micrometer.tagged.TaggedCircuitBreakerMetricsPublisher; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   CircuitBreakersHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreaker', 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator', 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.StatusAggregator' (OnClassCondition)

   CompositeMeterRegistryAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'io.micrometer.core.instrument.composite.CompositeMeterRegistry' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactory; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceConfiguration.Hikari matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   DataSourceHealthContributorAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate', 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator management.health.defaults.enabled is considered true (OnEnabledHealthIndicatorCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'dataSource' (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceHealthContributorAutoConfiguration#dbHealthContributor matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: dbHealthIndicator,dbHealthContributor; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceInitializationConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulator' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a single bean 'dataSource'; @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlR2dbcScriptDatabaseInitializer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceJmxConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.jmx.enabled=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   DataSourceJmxConfiguration.Hikari matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourcePoolMetricsAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource,io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry; SearchStrategy: all) found beans 'simpleMeterRegistry', 'dataSource' (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourcePoolMetricsAutoConfiguration.DataSourcePoolMetadataMetricsConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.jdbc.metadata.DataSourcePoolMetadataProvider; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'hikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProvider' (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourcePoolMetricsAutoConfiguration.HikariDataSourceMetricsConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate', 'org.springframework.transaction.TransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.JdbcTransactionManagerConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a single bean 'dataSource' (OnBeanCondition)

   DiskSpaceHealthContributorAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator management.health.defaults.enabled is considered true (OnEnabledHealthIndicatorCondition)

   DiskSpaceHealthContributorAutoConfiguration#diskSpaceHealthIndicator matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: diskSpaceHealthIndicator; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet' (OnClassCondition)
      - found 'session' scope (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DispatcherServletConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'jakarta.servlet.ServletRegistration' (OnClassCondition)
      - Default DispatcherServlet did not find dispatcher servlet beans (DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DefaultDispatcherServletCondition)

   DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'jakarta.servlet.ServletRegistration' (OnClassCondition)
      - DispatcherServlet Registration did not find servlet registration bean (DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DispatcherServletRegistrationCondition)

   DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration#dispatcherServletRegistration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (names: dispatcherServlet types: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'dispatcherServlet' (OnBeanCondition)

   EndpointAutoConfiguration#endpointCachingOperationInvokerAdvisor matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoker.cache.CachingOperationInvokerAdvisor; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   EndpointAutoConfiguration#endpointOperationParameterMapper matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.ParameterValueMapper; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'jakarta.servlet.Servlet', 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet' (OnClassCondition)
      - found 'session' scope (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration#basicErrorController matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration#errorAttributes matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorAttributes; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.DefaultErrorViewResolverConfiguration#conventionErrorViewResolver matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'dispatcherServlet'; @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (server.error.whitelabel.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - ErrorTemplate Missing did not find error template view (ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.ErrorTemplateMissingCondition)

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration#beanNameViewResolver matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration#defaultErrorView matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: error; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   FallbackConfigurationOnMissingBean#completionStageFallbackDecorator matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.github.resilience4j.spring6.fallback.CompletionStageFallbackDecorator; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)
...
```

Comment: what are the issues about this way ? there is another way is to use profiles, but IMHO I prefer what you are already doing !

Comment: I tried rephrasing to be more specific, but the issue is that the `TestConfig` class creates a DataSource bean that is always used in the test no matter what kinds of annotations I throw at the test.

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using? Your question states Spring Boot but your tests try very hard to avoid the use of the Spring Boot testing utilities and use the plain Spring test parts only.

Comment: Spring Boot 3.1. It was created in 2015 or so, and just moved over from 2.7 without any real changes (mostly due to avoiding CVE's).

Comment: You can also try to use reflection to override these fields. Here is a baeldung guide for it. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reflection-test-utils

Comment: @Dimitris I am not sure how that would help? The problem here is that two DataSource beans are created and that causes subsequent issues.

Comment: My idea was instead of creating a new Datasource for all tests, override it with reflection only when and where needed. I had used it only once myself to override a property in a single test.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `dataSource` method in `TestConfig` for one test without affecting other tests by using the `@Primary` annotation in the configuration class specific to that test. Here's an example:

Create a test-specific configuration class, call `TestSpecificConfig`, which takes an instance of `TestConfig`:

```java
@Configuration
public class TestSpecificConfig extends TestConfig {

     @Primary
     @Bean
     public DataSource dataSource() {
         final var hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
         hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:tc:postgresql:15:///databasename");
         return hikariDataSource;
     }
}
```

Within your test class (`RateLimiterTest`), use the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation to define a test-specific configuration class:

```java
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestSpecificConfig.class})
public class RateLimiterTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

     // ... the rest of your test code
}
```

This way, you create a custom configuration for your test (`TestSpecificConfig`) that replaces the `dataSource` method with the desired implementation. The `@Primary` annotation ensures that this bean has a higher priority than the one defined in the base `TestConfig` during test execution.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. This is more or less exactly what I did, except the addition of `@Primary`. Unfortunately, that made no difference. All tests run after test errors in just the same fashion as before. Still get `did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)` big error dump in later tests. I did hook into some of the bean creation methods after seeing your answer and at least I have verified that there is just a single DataSource for all tests, except for the one with the custom setup, where Spring lists two, but still manages to pick the right one. Yet, still the application crashes